# TC Server Vs JBoss Server

Tags: jboss, springsource

We are planning to migrate to a new WebServer (bye bye Websphere), the main considerations are

1. transaction management
2. persistence
3. message/event handling
4. maintainability
5. distributed architecture
6. MBD/EJB support

We are very happy with TC Server but the only problem is that it does not support EJB's and MDB's and we use them pretty heavily here, I head that you can use TC Server and JBoss together, did anybody try using it that way or is there other way that we can use EJB's and MDB's with TC Server ?

Any help appreciated

/srm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by TC you mean Apache's Tomcat, then yes: JBoss AS is bundled with an embedded Tomcat Servlet/JSP container. So, if you are happy with Tomcat, then JBoss might be a good option for you. And it supports all things you've mentioned.

1. JTA
2. JPA/Hibernate
3. JMS and MDB
4. ---
5. Yes, you can have JBoss AS in cluster provided your application supports it
6. Of course. JavaEE containers must support MDB and EJB.

Comment: tcServer is SpringSource's repacked Tomcat, with added bells and whistles.